# C++11 using delaration for constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, compiler-errors, arm

I tried to use the using-declaration of C++11 to write the constructor like the following

```
    class BaseDevice : public DeviceInterface
    {
    public:
        /**
         * @brief Constructor
         */
        BaseDevice();   
         ~BaseDevice(); 
      
    };

class LED : public BaseDevice
    {
    public:
        /**
         * @brief Constructor
         */
        using BaseDevice::BaseDevice;
        ~LED();    
    };
```

But I got the error from Arm Compiler "a using-declaration may not name a constructor or destructor". Does that mean, arm compiler cannot use derived constructor in C++11?

Comment: Did you mean for `A` to inherit from `Base`? What is your intent with the using declaration?

Comment: Yes, A is derived from Base, that is my typing mistake.

Comment: Don't type examples on the fly into the question. Prepare them offline, check they reproduce the error exactly, and then copy and paste them here. Please edit your post to contain a proper [mre].

Comment: The error message is what I copied from my console

Comment: please post real code. In the one you posted there is no derived constructor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found that ARM Compiler does not support inheriting constructor.

Answer (score -2):

You need not declare that your derived class uses the default constructor for the base class.  This is what happens by default unless you code it otherwise.

Comment: Yes, you are right, but I want to know why this error happened.

Comment: It happened because you used an invalid construct.  It is forbidden to do that in C++.

Comment: Well, the compiler says otherwise.

Comment: There's a vast difference between what compilers say and what determines if C++ is valid.

Comment: Well, that does not change the fact that the compiler is always right because you have no other possibility to compile.

Comment: "you have no other possibility to compile" you can always use another conforming compiler.